# SEGEGV with strlen for long string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, strlen

I am trying to compute the length of a long string however strlen function  For the following code sample fails giving SEGFAULT.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const char * genstring( long len){
    string str,str1;
    char *c;
    int min=97, max = 122; 
    int output;

    for( long i=0; i<len; i++){

        output = min + (rand() % static_cast<int>(max - min ));
        str = (char)output;
        str1.append(str);

    }
    c = (char *)str1.c_str();

    return (const char*)c;

}

int main(){
    const char *s = genstring(100000);
    cout << strlen(s);

}
```

Error in gdb  is as follows

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:203
203 ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
```

However for length of 60k the same program works. Also the same program runs using clang without any segfault.

Comment: `c = (char *)str1.c_str();` pointer to a temporary buffer, `return (const char*)c;` returns an invalid pointer

Comment: Also what is the point of this? You can just return a `std::string` instead of messing around with `char*`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return from the function the object `str1` is destroyed so the return from `c_str` doesn't appear to be guaranteed. You need to allocate a new string for that, like this for example:

```
c = strdup(str1.c_str()); // nb call free on the memory when done
```

You will need to call [free](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) when you're done with the string returned from [strdup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup).

**Edit**
[This reference to c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) does also say that any string manipulation on the original string object will invalidate the c_str that is returned. Destroying the object (by returning in your case) definitely qualifies as manipulation!

Comment: Return from `c_str` is guaranteed just fine. It's the `strlen` that has UB with the dangling pointer.

Comment: Thank you. This helped , also could you please tell why is this dependent on the length passed cause the same did work for lower length values.

Comment: @aradhyamathur because passing an invalid pointer to `strlen` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user2079303 if it was guaranteed beyond the duration of the object I would expect string operations to have no effect on it.

Comment: @aradhyamathur undefined behaviour is the cry here: how the computer uses memory that's no longer being used can be different between runs, builds, lengths of memory etc ... I would guess that the memory clean-up functions did something different when it was cleaning up the longer string (which would be encapsulated within the `string` object/class

Comment: @noelicus any particular work around to prevent it ?

Comment: My answer should solve it. What you were doing was undefined behaviour, i.e. it might work sometimes. Using the line I have given you will mean the string lasts as long as you need it - until you free it